# Tooltip cut into iframe

Tags: php, tooltip

In my web site I have an iframe tag with several little images, when I pass my mouse (onmouseover) I show the more large image (tooltip) but only a liitle part is showed due the iframe.

There is someone that can tell me how show the tooltip into iframe over the parent page?

(without use JQuery)

Thanks a lot

Comment: beside "make the iframe bigger" there isnt a solution for this. an iframe is a window embeded in another window, you also cant have a tooltip outside a browser window (viewable) or can you :-). Sorry there is no way, if you have access to the code in the iframe, you can try with javascript to communicate with the outer screent (parent.) and display the tooltip in this viewport.

Comment: Nice idea,
but, do you have some link or example to show me?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a jQuery solution for tooltips inside iframe

Here is the code:
https://github.com/TeamTypeform/Tooltip